# how to dynamically load small images on a game worldmapImage(which is bigger than screen size) and move those images as per the player's movements?

Tags: android

I am developing a game in android using java(on Eclipse).
In it there's a world map image of 5000 by 500 pixels.I have to display a part of that image on screen and i do that using the method that takes a source rectangle and a destination rectangle..
I also want some other small images if size 35 by 35 pixels to be displayed at certain points on the world map image but the constraint is that 
1) i want those images to be loaded only if that part(where those images have to be placed) of the world map image is visible on the screen,not otherwise.

2)i want those dynamically loaded images to move according to the player's movements i.e. it should give the impression that those images are a part of the world map image.
and
3)if the player collides with that small image,that image disappears ...

how do i handle it and which collision detection method should i use....
I would highly appreciate if somebody could help me with that....
and although i am clear with the basics ,i don't know have much experience with programming...but right now i am stuck with the above mentioned problem...

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you good enough.
I programmed games in c++ with CML (library).

Not 100% sure how it is done with android, but with CML. You can give an image a x, y position.
let's say, you screen is 100 x 100 pixels.
CML (probably Java android too) is the 0 x 0 point at the left top of the screen.
So if you want to place a small image somewhere else, you just say something like.

```
small_image.x = 500;
small_image.y = 100;
```

Then when you character walks to the right far enough, he will see it.

And with collision, you have to make a "box" around the image.
Have to look it up in my own code how I did that again, will reply later.

I am back:

```
int x, y; //Horizontal  and vertical position, respectively. I assume these refer to the upper left corner of the sprite.
int w, h; //Width and height of sprite, respectively.

 //Let's examine the x axis first:
  //If the leftmost or rightmost point of the first sprite lies somewhere inside the second, continue.
  if( (player.x >= small_image.x && player.x <= (small_image.x + small_image.w)) ||
      ((player.x + player.w) >= small_image.x && (player.x + player.w) <= (small_image.x + sprite_2.w)) ){
    //Now we look at the y axis:
  if( (player.y >= small_image.y && player.y <= (small_image.y + small_image.h)) ||
       ((player.y + player.h) >= small_image.y && (player.y + small_image.h) <= (small_image.y + small_image.h)) ){
      //The player seems to overlap the image.
```

However, this is C++ code, but will work in Java too I think, but now you have an idea.